# Trying to implement shopify webhooks but getting 'InternalServerError: stream is not readable'

Tags: next.js, shopify

I'm building an app for shopify and need to add the GDPR webhooks. My back end is handled using next.js and I'm writing a webhook handler to verify them. The [docs](https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks/configuration/https#step-5-verify-the-webhook) havent been very helpful because they dont show how to do it with node. This is my verification function.

```js
export function verifiedShopifyWebhookHandler(
    next: (req, res, body) => Promise
): NextApiHandler {
    return async (req, res) => {
        const hmacHeader = req.headers['x-shopify-hmac-sha256'];
        const rawBody = await getRawBody(req);
        const digest = crypto.createHmac('sha256', process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET).update(rawBody).digest('base64');
        if (digest === hmacHeader) {
            return next(req, res, rawBody);
        }

        const webhookId = req.headers['x-shopify-webhook-id'];

        return res.status(401).end();
    };
}
```

But I get this Error: error - InternalServerError: stream is not readable

I think it has to do with now Next.js parses the incoming requests before they are sent to my api. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the above function meant to run as an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) in Next.js?

Comment: Its a wrapper that wraps each of the webhook api routes to check if they are valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the answer. Next.js was pre parsing the body in the context which made it so that I couldn't use the raw body parser to parse it. By setting this:

```js
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
};
```

above the api function in the api file it prevented next from parsing it and causing the issue. I found the answer because people had the same issue integrating swipe and using the bodyParser.